# I am testing HTTP get method but there is an error "No module named ASCII"?

Tags: python, http

ASCII is installed but still getting this error. I tested by importing all the libraries in the error msg but could not solve it.

Complete Error Message here.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "re.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests,compile, ASCII
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>

    import urllib3
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool, HTTPSConnectionPool, connection_from_url
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 3, in <module>

    import logging
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, io, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections.abc
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\traceback.py", line 5, in <module>

    import linecache
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\linecache.py", line 11, in <module>

    import tokenize
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tokenize.py", line 33, in <module>

    import re
  File "C:\Users\naeem\Desktop\re.py", line 1, in <module>

    import requests,compile, ASCII
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ASCII'
```

Python Code I am running is here:

```
import requests,compile, ASCII

def main():
    res = requests.get("https://www.google.com/")
    print(res.text)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Can anybody help me out please?

Comment: It's probably because you've specified the `ASCII` module to be imported in your first line of code.

Comment: I tested it without importing it also. If I don't import ASCII error in the last line changes to  module 're' has no attribute 'ASCII', where re.py is the name of python code file

Comment: Your python file is named "re.py" which means that its module name is "re".  This conflicts with the standard library's "re" module, which is trying to be imported indirectly by requests.  You should change the name of your .py file.

Comment: I spent a lot of time figuring it out but could not. Just checked in PyCharm and it's working. BTW there was no conflict between re.py and standard library.

Answer (score 0):

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ASCII'
This means that don't exist a module named 'ASCII'.
Maybe it's useful curses.ascii

so:

import curses.ascii

You can find Documentation here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.ascii.html

Comment: It could not help.